# removing images from directory and their link from directory

Tags: php, database

i have images stored in a directory and their path in table .
I want that when a user deletes the image it is first removed from directory and then its link removed from the table.
i have used **unlink** function for this.
query for selecting record

```
$file_link_query="SELECT picture FROM pics_catalogue WHERE catalogue_id=".$_GET['catalogue_id'];
```

and the codde that remove the image from directory

```
mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
  $file_link_result=mysql_query($file_link_query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($file_link_result))
  {echo $row['picture'];
      unlink("user_data/".$vendor_id."/".$row['picture']);}
```

and after this i'm removing the data from table

```
$pics_delete_query="DELETE FROM pics_catalogue WHERE catalogue_id=".$_GET['catalogue_id'];
$pics_delete_result=mysql_query($pics_delete_query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

**the problem is that it removes the entry from database but doesnot delete the file.**

Comment: And your question? Also add a type for `$_GET['catalogue_id']`: `(int)$_GET['catalogue_id']` for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The path might be wrong or you might not have permission to the directory. Check and confirm.
If you have the permission then the path might be incorrect check the path you have specified. Its the path relative to your present working directory otherwise you can also use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and then append the path.

Comment: i have the permission to the directory. as i'm saving the data to the same directory so there is also no problem with the path.

Comment: then its impossible that the images don't get deleted

Comment: i checked the path executing the unlink separately and it deletes the file. i think some how the line is not working in the above code only.

Answer (score 0):

Check the full path

unlink($path);